# Accessing arrays from within a class

Tags: php

I have a config file that contains an array of settings/parameters. The problem I'm running into is accessing this array from within a class. My first guess was to do something like this.

**Settings File:**

```
$config = array (

    'db' => array (
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'password'  => 'password',
                'port'  => 3306,
                'database'  => 'my_db',
                'user'  => 'root'
            ),
    'email' => array (
                'username'  => 'someone@somewhere.com',
                'smtp'      => 'smtp.somewhere.com',
                'ssl'       => true,
                'password'  => 'my_password',
                'port'      => 587


            )
// other stuff



);
```

**The Confiuration class**

```
class CoreConfig
{
    static $confArray;

    public static function read($name)
    {
        return self::$confArray[$name];
    }

    public static function write($name, $value)
    {
        self::$confArray[$name] = $value;
    }

}
```

And use it like: `CoreConfig::write('username', $config['email']['username']);`. Example using it in a class:

**Usage**

```
class SomeClass {

    public function __construct() {} 

    public function getUserName() {
        return CoreConfig::read('username');
    }
}
```

Although this works, it feels like it's considered bad practice. Alternatively I can take the initial `$config` and load it right away in my `$confArray` instead "writing", which looks like an ever worse idea. Is there another approach to this?

Comment: Use $GLOBALS['config'] to access $config array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sure feels a bit weird to hard code anything in an application, even if you're doing a configuration file. There are many methods for doing what you're trying to do, but the most important thing is to keep all "hard coded" values at the same place.

If you have access to any kind of SQL to do your work, I would recommend to put all configurations values in a data table. Doing this, you avoid having any hard coded values directly in the code, since they're in a database.

**Config class**

```
class CoreConfig
{
    static $confArray = null;

    public static function read($name)
    {
        if(self::$confArray == null)
            self::loadConfig();
        return self::$confArray[$name];
    }

    private static function loadConfig()
    {
        self::$confArray = DatabaseManager::fetchAll("SELECT * FROM config");
    }
}
```

**Database Manager class**

```
class DatabaseManager
{
    private static $instance = null;
    private static $host = "YOUR HOST NAME HERE";
    private static $dbName = "YOUR DATABASE NAME";
    private static $dbUser = "YOUR DATABASE USER";
    private static $dbPass = "YOUR DATABASE PASSWORD";

    private function __construct() {}

    private static function getDb()
    {
        if(is_null(self::$instance))
        {
            self::$instance = new PDO("mysql:host=" .self::$host. ";dbname=" .self::$dbName, self::$dbUser, self::$dbPass);
            self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }


    public static function fetchAll($SQL)
    {
        $return = null;
        try
        {
            $return = self::getDb()->query($SQL)->fetchAll();
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            // If you want to display errors directly on the page
            echo "SQL Query Error<br />";
            echo "Request: $SQL<br />";
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $return;
    }
}
```

You may refer to [PDO Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) on php.net in order to add features to the Database manager. You will have to add more methods if you want to be able to write in the database using PHP.

If you have no database options, then you can use an XML or JSON configuration file and parse it into an array at the moment of reading its values.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perhaps the database option would be the best place to start since it's available. Though I have never actually done that type of setup before...

Comment: @Dimitri If you have enough time to learn it, that would be a great addition to your web programming knowledge. I've been using PHP with MySQL for more than 5 years now and I think its the best way to work in web for most of the cases. Otherwise, if you can't afford to leard it now, your method will work fine and you can update to a database system later with pretty much the same structure.

Comment: Yea, I just need to figure out how I'm going to set my tables and how to retrieve the data. My guess is to have a primary key, value, description and a type column and store them somewhere when the page loads. Not sure if it's appropriate to setup a singleton class to do this... Do you know of any good references I can read up on for this?

Comment: The structure looks fine for the table, you can edit it at any time anyway. A singleton is for sure a good practice for database access. I've worked on my database manager for years now but I can't find references that looks like it.

I did a singleton class packed into a static class, I don't know if it has a specific name. The goal is to use the class this way:

`DatabaseManager::fetchRow("SELECT * FROM config WHERE name = '" .$configName. "'");`

You just have to "hard code" the database access data in static variables inside this class and all the rest can be retrieved in the database.

Comment: Great! I'll look around and see if I find something. Thanks for the input!